# JavaScript - Separate mixed array into proper types

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, node.js

Suppose I have an array like `a=[1,3,4,{roll:3},7,8,{roll:2},9]` and I want two arrays with the following contents:

`b=[1,3,4,7,8,9]`

`c=[{roll:3},{roll:2}]`.

How do I separate the contents of the array?

Comment: You should have better titles, and did you try something?

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the array by comparing the datatypes of the contents, as `{roll:2}` is of type `object` and the numbers are of type `number`.

```
var numbers = [];
var rolls = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (typeof a[i] === 'object')
    rolls.push(a[i]);
  else
    numbers.push(a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a=[1,3,4,{roll:3},7,8,{roll:2},9];

var numbers = [];
var objs = [];
for(var item in a)
{
    if(typeof a[item] !== 'number')
    {
        objs.push(a[item]);
    }
    else{
        numbers.push(a[item]);
    }
}

console.log (numbers);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript array [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function like below

```
 var a = [1, 3, 4, {
     roll: 3
 }, 7, 8, {
     roll: 2
 }, 9];


 var result = a.reduce(function(res, item) {
     if (typeof item === 'object') {
         res.c.push(item);
     } else {
         res.b.push(item);
     }
     return res;
 }, {
     b: [],
     c: []
 });

 console.log(result.b);
 console.log(result.c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter the source array.

```
var a = [ 1 , 3 , 4 , {roll:3} , 7 , 8 , {roll:2} , 9 ]; 
var b = a.filter(function(element) { return Number(element) === element; });
var c = a.filter(function(element) { return Number(element) !== element; });
```

The crux is how to distinguish between the two kinds of items in the array: the test I used could be paraphrased as "if casting the element to a Number produces the element itself, it is a number". Type detection in javascript is a famously fraught project, and I won't go into it here; see Douglas Crockford's *Javascript: the Good Parts* for an extended discussion on the topic, with excellent sample code. Based on the kinds of elements you expect to find in your array, you may need to choose a more elaborate discriminator. You can test these things out in the browser's javascript console pretty easily. I did this to validate my test:

```
> Number(4) === 4
< true
```

-

This approach iterates over the source array twice. If you care about performance -- which will only be an issue if the source array has tens of thousands of items in it, or if your test is very expensive -- then you could accomplish the same result with a `forEach` that tests each item and appends it to one of two output arrays (or a `reduce` that emits something like `{ numbers: [], items: {}}`).

--

META: your title is not great. If you don't put some effort into your questions, you shouldn't expect a lot of effort in the form of answers. We're all doing out of the goodness of our chipotle burritos. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single loop with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and push according to the type of the element.

```js
var a = [1, 3, 4, { roll: 3 }, 7, 8, { roll: 2 }, 9],
    b = [],
    c = [];

a.forEach(function (el) {
    (typeof el === 'object' ? c : b).push(el);
});
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```